# Interactivity between a tree & a bar graph in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, bar-chart

Using D3.js, I need to create a tree visualization where clicking on any node would show a bar chart with underlying data.

To make it clear, here is a concrete example: Let's say I've a sample dataset with columns as:

Country,State,City,Sales,NumberOfTrips,NumberOfCustomers

Now the tree needs to start from country node and expand up to city.

And, by clicking any node, a bar chart should appear showing sales,  number of trips, and number of customers. Clicking on country, it should show the data at the country level and clicking a particular state node, the chart should show the drilled-down data.

Any help on this is most welcome. My main concern is the *linking* (interaction) between the tree and the bar chart.

Comment: Have you tried anything? In general, good StackOverflow questions show some code, and try to address a specific problem, rather than stating requirements and hoping someone does the work for you.

Comment: finally I solved it after some tries.It can be achieved by writing the svg creation code of the bar chart in the node click function of the dendrogram. if the same dataset is used for dendrogram & bar chart,then the data can easily be filtered on the basis of node clicked in the dendrogram.